# How to prevent Travis-CI to terminate a job?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, travis-ci

I have a bunch of files that need to be copied over to a `tmp/` directory and then compressed.

I tried `cp -rf $SRC $DST` but the job is terminated before the command is complete. The verbose option int help either because the log file exceeds the size limit.

I wrote a small function to print only a percentage bar, but I get the same problem with the log size limit so maybe I need to redirect stdout to stderr but I'm not sure.

This is the snippet with the function:

```
function cp_p() {
  local files=0
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do ((files++)); done < <(find -L $1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.*' -print0)
  local duration=$(tput cols)
  duration=$(($duration<80?$duration:80-8))
  local count=1
  local elapsed=1
  local bar=""

  already_done() {
    bar="\r|"
    for ((done=0; done<$(( ($elapsed)*($duration)/100 )); done++)); do
      printf -v bar "$bar▇"
    done
  }
  remaining() {
    for ((remain=$(( ($elapsed)*($duration)/100 )); remain<$duration; remain++)); do
      printf -v bar "$bar "
    done
    printf -v bar "$bar|"
  }
  percentage() {
    printf -v bar "$bar%3d%s" $elapsed '%%'
  }

  mkdir -p "$2/$1"
  chmod `stat -f %A "$1"` "$2/$1"

  while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
    file=$(echo $file | sed 's|^\./\(.*\)|"\1"|')
    elapsed=$(( (($count)*100)/($files) ))
    already_done
    remaining
    percentage
    printf "$bar"
    if [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
      dst=$2/$file
      test -d "$dst" || (mkdir -p "$dst" && chmod `stat -f %A "$file"` "$dst")
    else
      src=${file%/*}
      dst=$2/$src
      test -d "$dst" || (mkdir -p "$dst" && chmod `stat -f %A "$src"` "$dst")
      cp -pf "$file" "$2/$file"
    fi
    ((count++))
  done < <(find -L $1 -mindepth 1 -name '*.*' -print0)

  printf "\r"
}
```

This is the error I get

```
packaging files (this may take several minutes) ...

|▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ | 98%

The log length has exceeded the limit of 4 MB (this usually means that the test suite is raising the same exception over and over).

The job has been terminated
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `travis_wait cp -rf $SRC $DST`? See https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#Build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received for details.

Also, I believe that generally disk operations are rather slow on macOS builds. You might be better off compressing the file structure while the files are touched. Assuming you want to `gzip` the thing:

```
travis_wait tar -zcf $DST.tar.gz $SRC
```